# VB2010Express MessageBox appears multiple times

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Beginner here using VB2010 Express - using MessageBox.show IF/ELSEIF statements but my buttons have to be pressed several times, 1st btn once, 2nd twice, 3rd three times before the resulting message dialog box actually shows. I don't know how my Dim statements connects to this. Dim Result As ...

```
    Private Sub btnMessage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMessage.Click
        Dim Result As 
        If MessageBox.Show("Click something.", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
            MessageBox.Show("Aborted")
        ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Click something", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
            MessageBox.Show("Retrying.")
        ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Click something", " Title", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ignoring.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some very important very basic programming concepts. This is not the place to teach you those basics - that is what universities are for.

Enough to say you have three totally separate message boxes, hence they can appear three times.

The solution is to (properly) use variables:

```
Dim result
result = MessageBox.Show("Click something.", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
'store the chosen answer in the "result" variable, then use it to check the result

If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
    MessageBox.Show ("Aborted")
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
    MessageBox.Show ("Retrying.")
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
    MessageBox.Show ("Ignoring.")
End If
```

Comment: Sorry and thanks. I will go back and read a couple of books before I ask any more questions. I was only using the console prior to this as this was sadly my first attempt at controls which is where my confusion is originating from. Its a bigger step than I originally thought. I'll get there eventually. The sun is always shining, I just can't see it yet.